# How to display PDF with annotations and without embedded font?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pdf

I would like to display local PDF file (from `InputStream` or local `File`). Minimum upported Android version is not so important.

**Main assumptions:**

- PDF **do NOT has** embedded fonts, so is wrongly displayed (e.g. due to lack of `Helvetica` font on Android devices)
- PDF has annotations (extra layer)
- It is commercial application, so license has to be clear and known

## What I have tried:

### 1) AndroidPdfViewer (by barteksc)

**URL**

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

**Cons:**

- Not developed since 1,5 year
- No suport for "replacing" fonts (which do not exist on Android device like `Helvetica`)

**Pros:**

- Free!
- **A lot** of possibilities (swiping, tapping, callbacks, listeners)!!!
- Native code
- Easy to implement
- Can work without internet
- Can display local file from device (`Uri`, `File`, `byte[]`, `InputStream`, assets)
- Wide range of supported Android API versions
- Can be embedded as View in XML layout (`<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView ... />`)
- Can render PDF annotations (enabled by `enableAnnotationRendering(true)`)

**Example of Kotlin code:**

```
pdf_view
    .fromStream(inputStream)
    .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
    .onLoad(::onLoadCompleted)
    .onPageChange(::onPageChanged)
    .onError(::onLoadError)
    .load()
```

### 2) WebView + Google Drive Viewer

**URL**

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=

**Cons:**

- Has bandwidth limit for viewing or downloading
- Need active internet connection
- Very low performance (especially on older devices)
- Can not display local files (only from URL)

**Pros:**

- Free
- Easy to implement
- Can render PDF annotations
- Wide range of supported Android API versions
- Replacing unsupported fonts

**Example of Kotlin code:**

```
web_view.settings.run {
    javaScriptEnabled = true

    // For lowers than KITKAT
    pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
}

val pdfUrl = "http://your_url_to_pdf"

web_view.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=$pdfUrl")
```

### 3) WebView + `pdf.js` (by Mozilla)

**URL**

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

**Cons:**

- JavaScript in `WebView` (hard to maintain or develop by mobile developers)
- No support for PDF annotations

**Pros:**

- Free
- Can work without internet
- Can display local file from device (e.g. assets)

**Example of Kotlin code:**

```
val path: Uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test.pdf");

val pdfJs: String = "file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?file="

web_view.loadUrl(pdfJs + path);
```

### 4) Android native - `PdfRenderer`

**URL**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer

**Cons:**

- Lack of examples
- Need API 21
- No support for PDF annotations

**Pros:**

- Native Android solution (in API)
- Can work without internet

**Example of Kotlin code:**

```
val file = File(application.cacheDir, FILENAME)

val descriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)

val pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(descriptor)

val page = pdfRenderer.openPage(index)

val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.width, page.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
```

### 5) Opening PDF in external application

> Use `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` (with `Uri` as `application/pdf`) and start `startActivity()`

**Cons:**

- Can not embed in own application
- User may not have an application that supports PDF files (and throw `ActivityNotFoundException`)
- More code to write since API 24 (due to `FileUriExposedException` when not using `FileProvider`)

**Pros:**

- rather nothing

### 6) COMMERCIAL - PSPDFKit (by PSPDFKit GmbH)

**Cons:**

- VERY EXPENSIVE (a few thousands dollars / year)!

**Pros:**

- Everything on their site (I'm avoiding advertising)

### 7) COMMERCIAL - MuPDF (by Artifex)

**Cons:**

- VERY EXPENSIVE (several thousand dollars / year)!

**Pros:**

- Everything on their site (I'm avoiding advertising)

### Very old solutions

For example `vudroid`, `apdfviewer`, `droidreader` or `ebookdroid` from https://code.google.com/archive/ - not developed since many, many years